# Monitoring log for extension service worker lifecycle events

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm working on a very large service worker. There are many extension API calls, messaging with multiple content scripts, and also alarms. I am aware all of these reset the 30 seconds termination timer for the worker (see [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/service-workers/lifecycle)).  I'd like to understand ***exactly* how and when** the worker's life gets extended. For example, consider a monitoring log like this:

```
11:30:10.000 service worker wakeup due to chrome.tabs.onUpdated
11:30:13.000 chrome.tabs.sendMessage  
11:30:40.000 chrome.windows.create
11:31:05.000 chrome.tabs.onUpdated
11:31:35.000 service worker terminated due to idle 30 seconds
```

This log clearly shows how the service worker was able to stay awake for over a minute. This log helps me to ensure that my service worker stays awake predictably, and that I didn't miss any edge cases. It provides **explicit and comprehensive visibility** into the service worker lifecycle extension events for my **explicit understanding**.

Does Chrome already have such a log built-in? Or is it possible to patch the Chrome APIs to achieve the desired log?

Comment: Every `chrome` event (intended) and asynchronous `chrome` method (Chrome-only bug allowed by an unreasonable developer) resets the timer to 30 seconds. See also [Persistent Service Worker](/a/66618269).